# Subdomaining in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, subdomain

I am working on a project which is a app store. User can subscribe to many applications. I am creating a subdomain for each user and applications he subscribed are again running on subdomains.

Eg.

```
1). One user registers and selects subdomain as "mysubdomain". Then after logging in he will be accessing everything as "mysubdomain.appstore.com". 

2). After registration he subscribes an app, say, "discussion-board". 

3). Then the discussion board will be running on "discussion-board.mysubdomain.appstore.com"
```

Application which allows user which is running on app_store.com and the utility app discussion-board are two different applications.

I know the question sounds more like serverfault.com, but I am putting it here if it can be managed using rails.
I am using devise for authentication on rails 3

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you review:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

And take a look at doing the separate apps as Rack middleware.

Comment: I am through with http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3. I have one more question now. Do I need to do some settings in apache, like adding wildcard "*" for subdomains?

Comment: Yes, you will have to modify your configuration using `ServerAlias` and setting it to `*.appstore.com`. A quick google should find all the details you need.

Comment: I am still facing problems. I have configured apache as "*".appstore.com. everything.appstore.com redirects to appstore.com.  Now I have applications those will be subscribed by users and will be active on subdomains. These applications are separate from the subscription app. As an example subscriber subscribing "helpdesk" app will access it as helpdesk.subscriber_subdomain.appstore.com. For helpdesk I have created a virtual host with ServerAlias helpdesk.*.appstore.com but both of them doesn't work together. cont..

Comment: I have separate database per application per subscriber and I will be changing the database as per the domain name.

Comment: @Pravin Sorry. Really not sure. This seems like a bit of a bad design (giving each user their own database) IMO. My only suggestion would be to rework your database design to have associated records for each user.

Comment: @Kevin: In my system there can be subscribers for various applications with 1000-1500 users where as some of them can have users as low as 5-10. Like, for a helpdesk system there might be 5000 tickets per day logged in for a certain subscriber and may be 10-20 for another user. Over the time second user might suffer with that while accessing the database. Also two subscribers might be the competitors and a smallest bug in production may reveal information to the competitor which will be much more problematic beyond just being embarrassing :).