# Subdomaining in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, subdomain

I have a question posted [Subdomaining in rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871766/subdomaining-in-rails-3)
I am through with rail-3 subdomaining. I have one more question now. 
Is it required to add wildcard "*" to apache config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See (in the comments):

https://gist.github.com/45076